# getting listview text information

Tags: android, listview

i have a list view and i want to get the text on the item that is selected.

I tried this

```
mContactList.setOnItemLongClickListener(new OnItemLongClickListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> arg0,View arg1,int arg2,long arg3) {
            SharedPreferences pref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(Contacts.this);
            SharedPreferences.Editor edit = pref.edit();

            n = mContactList.getItemAtPosition(arg2).toString();    
            Log.v("Contacts", "List Name: " + n);
            edit.putString(Prefs.NAME, n);
            showDialog(1);
            return false;
        }
    });
```

but it gives me this in the log

```
List Name: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor@40522900
```

what do i need to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the key to this lies in the "View arg1" argument.

What kind of Views are you listing in the listView? If it is a list of plain TextViews, then arg1.getText() should do the trick (just like Spidy said).

If it is a more complex View which contains a textView, then first get the textView with:

```
TextView tv = (TextView) arg1.findViewById(R.id.text_view_id);
```

and then call getText() on that.

Answer (score 2):

The item clicked should be your View parameter. arg1 in your case. A typical ListView uses TextView to display items. So cast the View arg1 to TextView and then grab the text with getText();

```
String listItemSelected_TextValue = ((TextView) arg1).getText();
```